# htaccess rewriterule with accents give me internal server error 500

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, non-ascii-characters

I've a rewrite rule in my htaccess to check if the last segment is a alphabetic (including accented chars).

```
RewriteRule ^search/tag/([A-Za-záéíóú]+)$      page.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/tag/([A-Za-zàèìòù]+)$      page.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

why the first one works and the second one cause an internal server error 500?

The problem seems to be the "à" char, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use `B` flag with quotes in regex to fix 500 error:

```
RewriteRule "^search/tag/([A-Za-záéíóú]+)$" page.php?tag=$1 [L,B]

RewriteRule "^search/tag/([A-Za-zàèìòù]+)$" page.php?tag=$1 [L,B]
```

Comment: Adding quotes seems enough, never done it before, thanks.

However, someone knows why is the a-grave the problem?

Comment: Somehow Apache interprets there is space when it gets `à` character which is `C3A0` in UTF-8